# i_nal_ref_idc parameter in x264 encoding

Tags: encoder, x264

can anyone please tell me what i_nal_ref_idc parameter implies in x264 encoding?

for P frames,i_nal_ref_idc =2 (in general)
but if I make it = 0 what does it implies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means your telling the decoder this is a NOT a reference picture that may be refured by when decoding subsistent frames. So the decoder is able to forget this frame after decoded. If the decoder does free this frame from memory, then a future frame references it, you will get corrupt output.

Comment: so making i_nal_ref_idc = 0 during the encoding for P frame allows me to have direct encoding means all P frames in the GOP will only be dependent on the I frame and nothing else. I am attaching this encoder output can you please tell me whether it follows that direct encoding or not? x264 [debug]: frame=   0 QP=28.70 NAL=3 Slice:I Poc:0   I:32768 P:0    SKIP:0    size=335363 bytes 
x264 [debug]: frame=   1 QP=33.38 NAL=0 Slice:P Poc:2   I:924  P:11507 SKIP:20337 size=37314 bytes
x264 [debug]: frame=   2 QP=33.28 NAL=0 Slice:P Poc:4   I:1518 P:13596 SKIP:17654 size=55535 bytes

Comment: The nail_ref _idc is an output form the encoder, not an input.

Comment: But you can also specify in the encoder.c. I guess this means you are changing the NAL_PRIORITY. previously it was 2 (NAL_PRIORITY_HIGH, now I make it 0).                                             
else if( h->fenc->i_type == X264_TYPE_P )
    {
        i_nal_type    = NAL_SLICE;
        i_nal_ref_idc = 0; 
        h->sh.i_type = SLICE_TYPE_P;
      }  can you please clarify this slightly? Whether its a valid way of implementation for diect encoding as I discussed above. You can also refer this link (http://forum.doom9.org/archive/index.php/t-138024.html) for this.

Comment: By changing nal_ref_idc value from 2 to 0 for all P frames, I have observed the size of the P frames gets changed. How can this be justified in this context? Is it because of P frames are only referenced to I frame? But the size of the first P frame after I frame should be independent of both the situation (whether direct encoding or cumulative encoding), but I am getting a change of size in first P frame also after the I frame. Can u please tell me the possible reason or explanation behind this?